# Generating a vector of values from logical and numeric vectors of different lengths

Tags: r, vector, indexing

My question is certainly very basic, though I'm struggling to find a proper solution in this forum.
I have a logical vector (v1) and numeric (v2) vector with different lengths. The length of v2 is equal to the sum of TRUE values in v1.

My goal is to create a third vector (v3), with the same number of elements as v1, assigning NA whenever v1 == FALSE and using the values in v2 to "populate" v3 when v1 == TRUE.
Something like this:

`v1 <- c( FALSE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  FALSE,  FALSE , TRUE )`

`v2 <- c(3, 0, 2)`

Desired output (v3):
`NA, 3, 0, NA, NA, 2`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner with replace:

```r
replace(rep(NA, length(v1)), v1, v2)
[1] NA  3  4 NA NA  2
```

---

Or, with `[`:

```r
v1[v1] <- v2
# [1] 0 3 4 0 0 2

v1[v1 == 0] <- NA
# [1] NA  3  4 NA NA  2
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it correctly in an ifelse statement a la `v3 <- ifelse(v1 == T, v2, NA)` ?

Comment: The closer you can do from an ifelse statement is with `replace`. See edit.

Comment: 'replace' works perfectly. Using [ will not give the desired output if v2 takes 0 as values.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

v1 %>% na_if(F) %>% replace(which(.), v2)

#> [1] NA  3  0 NA NA  2
```

Answer (score 1):

For educational purposes. A throwaway function, using `NA` propagation.

```
(\(){.=v1[NA];.[v1]=v2;.})()
[1] NA  3  0 NA NA  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
v1 <- c( FALSE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  FALSE,  FALSE , TRUE )
v2 <- c(3, 4, 2)
v3<-v1

v3[v3==T] <- v2
v3[v3==0] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I think this may not apply if v2 has 0 as a possible value